# rails app commits SQL transaction but no change in actual table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

my rails app generates the following server queries

```
Processing by ResponsesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WJBM8CJQaLxkRfC3/cGimaEytM3EvqCWhOmfX1WBRQA=", "response"=>{"q_id"=>"4", "taker_id"=>"10", "value"=>"4", "text"=>"fsfsf"}, "commit"=>"Create Response", "locale"=>"en"} 

Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
(0.1ms)  

begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "responses" ("created_at", "q_id", "taker_id", "text", "updated_at", "value") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 11 Oct 2013 18:54:10 UTC +00:00], ["q_id", 4], ["taker_id", 10], ["text", "fsfsf"], ["updated_at", Fri, 11 Oct 2013 18:54:10 UTC +00:00], ["value", 4]]

(2.3ms)  commit transaction

default_url_options is passed options: {}
```

However, there is no actual change I can see in my local mysql db (on macos)

mysql> use medisupply
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

```
Database changed
mysql> select * from responses
    -> ;
Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

Any ideas what could be the reason for that? Its driving me insane.

my database.yml config:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  host: localhost
  database: medisupply
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

thanks heaps

Comment: Are you sure your server is running in development mode? What if you insert a record from rails console?

Comment: Check the DB you are using to see the data. Same env as the server ?

Comment: I tried it in the console and there it worked. Then just restarted the server - that solved it! thanks for the input!